# SAS: If first row equals next row, return only first row until last

Tags: loops, sas, do-loops

I'm trying to return unique emails for specific IDs. Some IDs have multiple emails but sometimes there are duplicates. I'm thinking a loop might do it but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
HAVE
ID  ACCOUNT_EMAIL
114 email_1@gmail.com
114 email_1@gmail.com
114 email_2@gmail.com
114 .

WANT
ID  ACCOUNT_EMAIL
114 email_1@gmail.com
114 email_2@gmail.com
```

```
CREATE TABLE test AS 
SELECT DISTINCT
ID
,UPPER(ACCOUNTEMAILADDRESS) AS Account_Email
FROM DATABASE
;QUIT;

PROC SORT DATA=test;
BY ID
descending Account_Email;
Run;

DATA test;
SET test;
BY ID descending Account_Email;
IF last.Account_Email AND Account_Email = '' THEN dupIND = "Y";
ELSE dupIND = "N";
;RUN;
```

Comment: In the future please include any code you've tried even if it doesn't work.

Comment: Please modify your desired output to match the code suggested, e.g include the DupIND variable and any other variables. Will there be cases where there is only missing emails? If so, how are those handled?

Answer (score 2):

If the data is not sorted you can use a hash object to track observed keys (id+email)

```
data want;
  set have;
  uc_email = upcase(email);
  if 0 then do;
    declare hash h();
    h.defineKey('id', 'uc_email')
    h.defineDone();
  end;

  if h.check() ne 0 then do;
    h.add();
    status = '1st';
  end;
  else 
    status = 'dup';
  
  drop uc_email;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more clearly stated as find unique entries in a table.

Three common ways are proc sort, data step and SQL using Distinct.

Sort is one of the easiest, use the NODUPKEY option.

```
proc sort data=have out=want nodupkey;
by id account_email;
run;
```

Data step requires a sort anyways.

```
proc sort data=have;
by id account_email;
run;

data want;
set have;
by id account_email;
if first.account_email;
run;
```

SQL distinct

```
proc sql;
create table want as 
select distinct id, account_email
from have;
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks, those do work to remove the duplicates but I was more looking for a 'check' to compare if the first row equals next row, then return only first row until last (in that group).
Some of the IDs also have duplicates and blanks so I have code to sort so the blanks are last then mark it as "Y" to delete. I added in some code and a different example above.

Comment: You could account for the missing by just adding  a where statement? "Where not missing(account_email);" in the relevant locations unless you may have IDs that only have missing emails.